# Can I create a selector with an image?

Tags: css, image, css-selectors

I'm learning the basics of basics right now. I just learned about selectors.

For example,

```
.DivClass{ 
    background-color: dodgerblue; 
    width: 160px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 10px dashed black;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

where

```
div class="DivClass"
```

Am I able to do something similar with images? All I know of is

```
img src="www.link"
```

Using Google, I found

```
 img {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 150px;
    }
```

But that would only work if you only have one image, right? How do you name the images like you would a class or ID?

Also, using ./pre, how do you put less/greater than signs inside? If I try, it just shows up blank.

Comment: What you wrote in your examples doesn't make any sense. What are the `<pre>` tags for?

Comment: They're only to put the code inside this post so it looks like code. Except it won't let me use less/greater than signs inside. How do I do like a code snippet?

Comment: You either indent the code four spaces or select the code markdown above the entry textbox. This is markdown and you cannot format posts using HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about HTML with CSS is pretty normal create classes and use it into img tag. Example:

```
.img-container {
   width: 100%;
   heigth: 100%
}
```

```
<img class="img-container" src="img_car.jpg" alt="Car">
```

I strongly recomend that you learn more about CSS. 
W3 has fully documentation about web stuff: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/

Also when you want to add css directly into your HTML file you have to use style tag. 
Take a look into the exemple I did at the snippet below:

```html
<body>
<style>
.DivClass{ 
    background-color: dodgerblue; 
    width: 160px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 10px dashed black;
    margin: 50px;
  }
  
.image-container {
  width: 50px;
  heigth: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  }
</style>
<div class="DivClass"></div>
<img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg" class="image-container" >
</body>
```

Answering your question, when you apply CSS to the tag name as

```
img {
 **any style here**
}
```

Means that all img tags into your project will get the style you've set into the selector img {}.

When you create a specifics selector, for example .image-container {}, means that only tags that received this class will get the styles inside him. Example:

```
<img class="image-container" src="..." >

<div class="image-container" > blablabla </div>
```

And ID selector you use only when you want to sett style just for an one and only one specific element, Example:

```
#testing-id {
   color: red
}
```

```
<p id="testing-id"> blablalba </p>
```

I hope that explanation helps.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: I have been using the style tag. Is there a way to post my whole code here without it breaking things? How did you enter a code snippet? Basically I'm just trying to see if you can add multiple images (like you can have multiple paragraphs) and have different settings for each.

Comment: I figured it out!! I just had to look at it some more, haha. Now I know how to create classes for images :)

Comment: Nice! Sorry for the delay, but yes is just simple as I explained. You can create any classes as you wish and apply then into any element that you want. 
So, if the problem is solved, don't forget to close the Question. 

And to add code snippet or just some code parts you just have to pay attention into the textarea options in the top bar when you are creating your question, because there you'll find all this options to insert into your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!